# Highlight corect row of DataGrid in WPF control after DataContext rebind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, highlight, selecteditem

I have `UserControl` with `DataGrid` and this `UserControl` is added like this:

```
<local:TouchScrollDataGrid DataContext="{Binding ArticlesProposalsGeneral}" />
```

`ArticlesProposalsGeneral` is a class with fields:

```
public PayloadItem SelectedItem
{
    get => _selectedItem;
    set { _selectedItem = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem)); }
}
public List<PayloadItem> FullList
{
    get => _fullList;
    set
    {
        _fullList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FullList));
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Window));
    }
}
```

`DataGrid` have this settings:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
```

Now when I store ID of selected item and did like this:

```
ArticlesProposalsGeneral.FullList = DbCache.ArticlesProposalsGeneral;
```

And then find this item on `FullList` and set `SelectedItem` I can't make corect item highlighted - it seams that item is selected because when I use other buttons from control it oparting on correct item. But highlighted is always first item.

Comment: Are you saying that the item isn't selected or highlighted or both?

Comment: Item is not highlighted.

Comment: So what did you do to highlight it? Read [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/11/08/how-to-programmatically-select-and-focus-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid-in-wpf/).